# Python Matplotlib Pie chart merge two slices with identical titles together

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm doing a matplotlib project with pie charts and **would like to merge two slices in a pie chart with identical titles together to form one big slice with the same title**.

[image]

However, matplotlib just leaves the slices seperated, even though they have the same title.

May I know how I can do that? Thanks.

And yes, some code.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
list0 = [1,2,3]
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "banana"]
plt.pie(list0, labels = list1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocess your titles and values then draw the chart:
We loop through the `list0` (the `values`) and `list1` (the `titles`) together, and make each of the `titles` as the `key` of the `dictionary` then add the corresponding `value` from the `list0` to that `key`. So the values of the titles with same name will be added to one and the same `{key: val}` in the dictionary.
When all the items are examined, we return the list of the `keys` of the dictionary as the `titles` and the corresponding `values` as the values of the charts for each `title`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def merge_slices(list0, list1):
    from collections import defaultdict
    dict_slices = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for val, title in zip(list0, list1):
        dict_slices[title] += val
    return list(dict_slices.values()), list(dict_slices.keys())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list0 = [1,2,3]
    list1 = ["apple", "banana", "banana"]
    merged_list0, merged_list1 = merge_slices(list0 ,list1)
    plt.pie(merged_list0, labels = merged_list1)
    plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

> `defaultdict` will create a `key` and set a `default value` for the keys which are not in the dictionary. In the snippet above, we set it in a way that, it will set `0` for the key which wasn't in the dictionary before.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it would be fastest to add code that aggregates values with the same title.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
list0 = [1,2,3]
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "banana"]

m = {k:sum([list0[i] for i, l in enumerate(list1) if l == k ]) for k in set(list1)}

plt.pie(m.values(), labels = m.keys())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it could be even better if the code was not all squeezed on line 5 and if you could explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

this can do,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

list0 = [1, 2, 3]
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "banana"]

sourceDict = {}
for i, j in zip(list1, list0):
    if not i in sourceDict:
        sourceDict.update({i: j})
    else:
        sourceDict[i] += j

plt.pie(sourceDict.values(), labels=sourceDict.keys())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]